# Less than n loops for solving the 'n queens' with no use of recursion?

Tags: c, programming-languages, brute-force

Is there a way without using a recursive function to solve the 8 queens problem with say, two or three loops? I am trying (in C) to iterate over all squares and to assign a queen at each square and check. The problem is that even iterating with loops 64 times doesnt help because for each assignment in a given line I gotta check all possible positions of different lines. But I have a feeling I can somehow do it with less than 8 loops. Even if I just want to use bruteforce I believe there is a way to do it with less than 8 loops but I can't seem to find anyone talking about it.

Is there such an implementation?

How can I iterate through all 64 squares while checking all possible configurations of 8 queens or close to it and yet not using 8 loops?

Comment: You have a solution, mabye one which gets close to what you want to achieve? Please show it.

Comment: Do it in one loop on numeric values encoding the board... such as octal 8-digits numbers, where each digit is encoding each queen position. Dunno what you are going to achieve by that though...

Comment: I suggest you read about [Lin-Kernighan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lin%E2%80%93Kernighan_heuristic). I seem to recall it being developed specifically for solving n queens.

Comment: Yunnosch@   No, I don't.  I did code the program apart from this part.  I just did two whiles up to 64 and even added some two fors inside.  Nothing helps as I gotta go through all possible positions.   That's why I am asking...

Comment: Your question is about how to achieve in a certain way with additional requirments. It is not about how to achieve it at all. If you cannot achieve at all, then ask a different question. If you can achieve, but not with the additional requirement, then do so and show the code. This is simply about demonstrating your own effort and avoiding the impression that you expect other people to write an advanced version of something you did not even do basically. Showing the basic solution also gives a context for the solutions, i.e. where is the input coming from, how is the output needed.

Comment: In 99% of all cases when you tag more than one language, your question is to broad. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: perhaps applying a different strategy to the problem will help. search dynamic programming and how to apply it to the 8 queens problem and perhaps you will find something useful

Comment: Yunnosch@  Not sure what you are on about.   It is a general question of how to achive an exustive result wihtout using all loops.  Why would it help that I post something?  Since it doesnt work.  Thats not at all about   " expect other people to write an advanced version of something you did not even do basically"   since it's about an idea which  I lack as for now.  What else can I do?  My implemtaion doesnt work and yet I know how to do it recursively but I am asking for an idea without recursion. I couldn't help but post this question. I dont see what else I can do.

Comment: Yes, it is possible see this implementation in C: https://github.com/fbergo/examples/blob/master/8q.c

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. Short pseudo code below, see https://github.com/fbergo/examples/blob/master/8q.c for valid C code.

```
col = 1
qrow[1..8]  = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}

while(true)
    if (qrow[col] == 8) {
         if (col > 1) { 
              qrow[col]=0;
              col--; 
              continue;
         } else {
              return FAIL;
         }
    } else {
       qrow[col]++;
    }

    // check if queens attack each other
    bad = 0;
    for(i=1;i<=7 && !bad;i++) {
       for(j=i+1;j<=8 &&!bad;j++) {
          if (qrow[i]!=0 && qrow[i]==qrow[j]) bad=1;
          if (qrow[i]!=0 && qrow[j]!=0 && abs(i-j)==abs(qrow[i]-qrow[j])) bad=1;
       }
    }

    if (bad) continue; // queens in conflict, can't advance to col+1
    if (col==8) return SUCCESS; // queens don't touch, 8 columns filled
    ++col; // advance to next column
}
```

Comment: To generate all possibilities you'd need to change the `if (col==8) return SUCCESS` line to save/output the current solution and return to the previous column ( `if (col==8) { output(); qrow[col]=0; col--; continue; }`, and `return FAIL` becomes `return END`, for the sake of semantics.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: Original question tagged `java`, so this is a Java solution.*

A chessboard is 64 squares, and we want to place 8 queens that can't attack each other. To quickly search for an open square, i.e. a square that cannot be attacked by already placed queens, we can use a 64-bit `long` to represent the entire chessboard, and use bit-manipulation and the [`Long.numberOfTrailingZeros()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#numberOfTrailingZeros(long)) method to find an open square.

We need some helper methods. First, a method for marking squares blocked by a queen at a given position.

```
private static long blockedSquaresWithQueenAt(int pos) {
    // Set vertical bits
    long board = 1L << (pos & 7);
    board |= board << 8;
    board |= board << 16;
    board |= board << 32;

    // Set horizontal bits
    long mask2 = 1L << (pos & ~7);
    board |= ((mask2 << 8) - 1) ^ (mask2 - 1);

    // Set diagonal bits
    for (int p = pos - 9; p >= 0 && (p & 7) != 7; p -= 9)
        board |= 1L << p;
    for (int p = pos - 7; p >= 0 && (p & 7) != 0; p -= 7)
        board |= 1L << p;
    for (int p = pos + 7; p < 64 && (p & 7) != 7; p += 7)
        board |= 1L << p;
    for (int p = pos + 9; p < 64 && (p & 7) != 0; p += 9)
        board |= 1L << p;

    return board;
}
```

Second, a method to print the board, with optional marker of a single queen position. Printing with marker was useful during development/testing.

```
private static void printBoard(long board, int markPos) {
    for (int pos = 0; pos < 64; pos++) {
        System.out.print(pos == markPos ? '\u25CB' : (board & (1L << pos)) == 0 ? '\u00B7' : '\u25CF');
        if ((pos & 7) == 7)
            System.out.println();
        else
            System.out.print(' ');
    }
}
```

Here is example of how it works, with queen at row 2, column 4, aka at position 20 *(all 0-based)*.

```
printBoard(blockedSquaresWithQueenAt(20), 20);
```

```
· · ● · ● · ● ·
· · · ● ● ● · ·
● ● ● ● ○ ● ● ●
· · · ● ● ● · ·
· · ● · ● · ● ·
· ● · · ● · · ●
● · · · ● · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
```

Since we want to quickly skip blocked squares, using the `numberOfTrailingZeros()` method, we want blocked squares to be 0-bits, so we invert that:

```
printBoard(~ blockedSquaresWithQueenAt(20), -1);
```

```
● ● · ● · ● · ●
● ● ● · · · ● ●
· · · · · · · ·
● ● ● · · · ● ●
● ● · ● · ● · ●
● · ● ● · ● ● ·
· ● ● ● · ● ● ●
● ● ● ● · ● ● ●
```

That is an example of our `long` board with one queen placed.

Now for the main logic. We use an array of size 8 so we can quickly backtrack when needed. Having array eliminates the need for recursion.

We then place the first queen (queen 0), mark blocked squares, find first unblocked square for second queen, and repeat until all 8 queens placed, backtracking as needed.

When we have 8 queens placed, we build and print a board of those 8 queens, then backtrack to find more solutions.

```
private static void solve() {
    int[] posForQueen = new int[8];
    long[] board = new long[8];
    posForQueen[0] = -1;
    // Keep trying until we backtrack from queen 0
    for (int queen = 0; queen >= 0; ) {
        // Find next open square for current queen
        posForQueen[queen]++;
        if (queen != 0)
            posForQueen[queen] += Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(board[queen - 1] >>> posForQueen[queen]);
        // Backtrack if no open square found
        if (posForQueen[queen] >= 64) {
            queen--;
        } else {
            // Build new board with open squares, accounting for all queens placed so far
            board[queen] = ~ blockedSquaresWithQueenAt(posForQueen[queen]);
            if (queen > 0)
                board[queen] &= board[queen - 1];
            // Advance to next queen if there are more queens to place
            if (queen < 7) {
                posForQueen[queen + 1] = posForQueen[queen];
                queen++;
            } else {
                // Build and print board with all 8 queen positions
                long queens = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                    queens |= 1L << posForQueen[i];
                System.out.println();
                printBoard(queens, -1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All solutions:

```
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·

● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·

● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·

● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·

· ● · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · ● · · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · · ● · · ·

· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · ● · · · ·

· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · ● · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·

· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·

· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · ● · · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · · ● · · ·

· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · ● · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·

· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
● · · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·

· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · · ● · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · ● · · · ·

· · ● · · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·

· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·

· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
● · · · · · · ·

· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · · ● · ·

· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · ● · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·

· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · ● · · · ·

· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · ● · · ·

· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · · ● · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · ● · · · ·

· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· ● · · · · · ·

· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
● · · · · · · ·

· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · · · · · ●
● · · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·

· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · · · · · ●
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·

· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · · ● · · ·

· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · ● · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·

· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·

· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·

· · · ● · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·

· · · ● · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· ● · · · · · ·

· · · ● · · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · · ● · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·

· · · ● · · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · · · · · ●
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·

· · · ● · · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · ● · · ·
● · · · · · · ·

· · · ● · · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · · ● · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·

· · · ● · · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·

· · · ● · · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · · ● · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·

· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·

· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·

· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · ● · · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·

· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · ● · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·

· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·

· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●

· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· ● · · · · · ·

· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
● · · · · · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · · ● · · ·

· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·

· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · ● · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·

· · · · ● · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · ● · · · · ·

· · · · ● · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · ● · · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·

· · · · ● · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·

· · · · ● · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · ● · · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·

· · · · ● · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · · ● · ·
● · · · · · · ·

· · · · ● · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · ● · · · · ·

· · · · ● · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
● · · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·

· · · · ● · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·

· · · · ● · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · ● · · · ·

· · · · ● · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· ● · · · · · ·

· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·

· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·

· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
● · · · · · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·

· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●

· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · ● · · · ·

· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · ● · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · · ● · ·
· ● · · · · · ·

· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · ● · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·

· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · ● · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·

· · · · · ● · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · ● · · · ·

· · · · · ● · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · ● · · · ·

· · · · · ● · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · ● · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·

· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·

· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · ● · · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · · ● · · ·

· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · ● · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·

· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●

· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
● · · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·

· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·

· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · ● · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·

· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · ● · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·

· · · · · ● · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · ● · · · · ·

· · · · · ● · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·

· · · · · ● · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●

· · · · · ● · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·

· · · · · ● · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·

· · · · · · ● ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·

· · · · · · ● ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · ● · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·

· · · · · · ● ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · ● · · ·

· · · · · · ● ·
· · ● · · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · ● · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·

· · · · · · ● ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · ● · · · ·

· · · · · · ● ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
● · · · · · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·

· · · · · · ● ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· · · · · ● · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·

· · · · · · ● ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· · · · · · · ●
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·

· · · · · · · ●
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · ● · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·

· · · · · · · ●
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · ● · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·

· · · · · · · ●
· · ● · · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · ● · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · ● · · · ·

· · · · · · · ●
· · · ● · · · ·
● · · · · · · ·
· · ● · · · · ·
· · · · · ● · ·
· ● · · · · · ·
· · · · · · ● ·
· · · · ● · · ·
```